# Building an ant jar signing tool

Tags: ant, jar, jar-signing

I am trying to use ant to sign about 40 some jars (in the same folder) with the same key store, but am having trouble figuring out the ant signjar task documentation. Any tips? Is there a better way to quickly sign jars that I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing to sign the jars in place.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="jarSigner" default="signer">
  <target name="signer">
    <signjar alias="..." keystore="myKeys" storepass="...">
      <path>
          <fileset dir="C:\...\lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </path>
    </signjar>
  </target>
</project>
```

(the "..." just is a place holder)

This seemed to work just fine.

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html is a super useful link to using this tool

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_data_types.htm is useful for understanding the jar locating part of the file